# Is it desirable to talk about flaws in an interview?

Tags: interviewing

After an interview I had I realized I had talked openly about a flaw I have, which I'm not sure is desirable in an interview where the goal is to make appear as marketable as possible. At the same time everyone has flaws and should be aware of them, so showing that to the employer seems okay. I am assuming flaws like personality/character deficits or minor health issues. Not something with either a heavy stigma attached or that will make the job impossible to do.

Comment: Say nothing about it, ever.

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not *ideal* to talk about your flaws in an interview, unless you're spinning it into a positive (*"sometimes I think I'm just too much of a workaholic"*)  That being said, it's not *necessarily* a torpedo in the water, either.

How do you feel about the rest of the interview?  Did it go well, overall?

I would just try to forget any implications of what happened and move on.  If *they* bring it up in the future, just say you were trying to be open and honest and got carried away (ie: the truth.)  Being self-aware of your own flaws means you can work to improve them over time.  If they don't mention it, you don't either.

Comment: It did go well overall. I fumbled a bit during the technical part but the question I asked sparked a nice conversation towards the end of the interview.

Answer (score 2):

If you talk about how you *adressed* a flaw of yours, then it should be fine. I very much prefer people who tell me how they overcome flaws or how they share tasks in a way that their flaws don't matter instead of persons who tell me that they are perfect.

Comment: In fact I was talking about a side project that I was working on to address a flaw I have. So perhaps the damage is not too bad :)